# Changing the MVC folder structure

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, razor, view

When I create a project the folder structure usually goes something like:

- Models

  - SomePage

    - SomePage.cs
- Controllers

  - SomePage

    - SomePageController.cs
- Views

  - SomePage

    - Index.cshtml
  - Web.config

I would like to create a structure like:

- MVC

  - SomePage

    - Models

      - SomePage.cs
    - Controllers

      - SomePageController.cs
    - Views

      - Index.cshtml

I have been able to overwrite the RazorViewEngine to correctly search for my views. However my Razor Views are not recognizing the name 'model'. I believe it has something to do with the Web.config in the Views folder. How do I accommodate my new structure?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking some thing like Areas in MVC, show [this link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/area-in-asp.net-mvc)